# How to get the instances of all views created by an adapter?

Tags: java, android, gridview, instance, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ArrayAdapter` for a `GridView`, As you can see in the code I populate the `GridView` using the `getView` method with a custom view that called: `GridViewCell`.

Now on a click of this custom view there is a `FlipAnimation` method run that works great for the clicked view. What I want to achieve is to run the same animation method for all the other custom views currently in the adapter, so I need to get the instances of all the other views (there are 4 view in the adapter, so I need to get instances of the other 3).

```
public class AnswersGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Answer>
{   
private static final String TAG = AnswersGridAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<Answer> answersList;
private Context context;
private MainActivity activity;
private QuestionGridFragment fragment;
private View view;

public AnswersGridAdapter(QuestionGridFragment fragment, Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Answer> answersList) 
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, answersList);
     this.answersList = new ArrayList<Answer>();
     this.answersList.addAll(answersList);
     this.context = context;
     this.activity = (MainActivity)context;
     this.fragment = fragment;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final View view = new GridViewCell(context);

    if (answersList.get(position).isChecked())
    {
        ((GridViewCell)view).FlipToBackWithoutAnimation();
    }

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ((GridViewCell)view).FlipAnmiation();
            if (answersList.get(position).isChecked())
            {
                answersList.get(position).setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                answersList.get(position).setChecked(true);
            }

            activity.getEstimatedCostTextView().setText(String.valueOf(activity.getEstimatedCost()));
            fragment.flipOtherChosenAnswer(position);
        }
    });

    ((GridViewCell)view).setTextToTitleTextView(answersList.get(position).getAnswerText());
    return view;
}
}
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
public void flipOtherChosenAnswer(int position) 
{
    int cellCount = answersAdapter.getCount();
    for (int i=0; i < cellCount; i++ )
    {
            ((GridViewCell)answersAdapter.getView(i, null, null)).FlipAnmiation();
    }
}
```

but that didn't help me. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you manages click in the `onItemClick`, the first argument should be the AdapterView, and trought it you can access its children.

```
int count = adpaterViewInstance.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   View childAt = adpaterViewInstance.getChildAt(i);
}
```

Edit:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adpaterViewInstance, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will try this options. But currently I manage my clicks from the getView method of the adapter and not from the gridView instance. isn't there another option to get the instances of the children?

Comment: as far as I know, no there is not. But wait for another answers

Comment: Ho Ok, But basically the AdapterView is the View that contains all the children the ArrayAdapter has created? thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I finally did, from the fragment that contains the `GridView` I run this method, that get all the children of the `GridView` and run the animation method on each one of them.

```
public void flipOtherChosenAnswer(int position) 
{
    int cellCount = gvQuestionAnswers.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i < cellCount; i++ )
    {
        if (i != position && qustionAnswersList.get(i).isChecked())
        {
            ((GridViewCell)gvQuestionAnswers.getChildAt(i)).FlipAnmiation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eheheh yes it's an old post BUT you have accepted your own response after the right response from Blackbelt? it's cool...